# How to redirect any website by clicking an image in html where framework is Django?

Tags: html, django

[image: Sample Image]

Here, I want to redirect **[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)** if I click that Facebook logo but as I have a port number of  **127.0.0.1:8000** therefore after clicking the image I'm redirecting **http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.facebook.com** and for that I'm getting **Page Not Found(404) Error**
How can I fix this so that it will only redirect fb or insta?

```
  <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end list-unstyled d-flex">
          <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-muted" href="www.facebook.com"><img src="/static/fb.png"></a></li>
          <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-muted" href="www.instagram.com"><img src="/static/insta.png"></a></li>
          <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-muted" href="www.twitter.com"><img src="/static/twitter.jpg"></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because HTML thinks you want to redirect to a sub directory or something. Instead your href should include a `https://` before the domain, for example:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="/static/fb.png"></a>
```